# BeagleBone black bluetooth connect to android with no passkey

Tags: android, ubuntu, bluetooth, beagleboneblack

I have a beaglebone black with ubuntu installed on it. I have a bluetooth usb dongle and all the bluetooth libraries. I am trying to disable the pairing and connection pins, meaning i want to make it so anything with bluetooth can connect to it straight away. I can not figure out how. Can anyone with experience help me out?

If its not possible, I want to at least make it so I can use default passkey like 0000 to connect to it.